# I'm getting a connection timed out error with SVN after installing OS X Yosemite

Tags: xcode, macos

Yesterday I updated OS X to Yosemite from Mavericks.  Today, any time I try to execute commands in SVN (no matter which client I use, including command-line), I get the following error:

`svn: E175012: Unable to connect to a repository at URL '<correct path>'
svn: E175012: Connection timed out`

This happens with all of my repos.  There is no delay that would indicate a time out, the error returns immediately.

If I browse to the repo path in Chrome it loads successfully.

I've updated Xcode to `6.0.1` and the command line tools as well.

When I call `which svn` I get: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/svn`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the client I normally use (Versions) has a crash bug in Yosemite.  The fix for that, which I carried out yesterday, is here: [Versions crashing in OS X Yosemite](http://help.blackpixel.com/kb/versions/versions-crashing-in-os-x-yosemite-1010)

That fix has the side effect of breaking SVN (but it stops the Versions crashes!).

Reverting the change gets rid of the error message I was seeing.